# how to keep UDP socket connection open between 2 hosts

Tags: c++, c

I'm working on a simple chatroom based on `C++` and `UDP`, and I'm using [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/udp-server-client-implementation-c/) as a base. Every time client-server are saying "hello" to each other, both of them are ending their processes and nothing else, but I'd like to keep the socket open after that, so I can send something else and/or something like that, but haven't found a way to do so, so how do I do such thing? Haven't found much info on what I need, so any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add loops into the code to keep receiving and sending.

Comment: @kaylum, for example, `while(True) { // }`?

Comment: Yes, that is one way.

Comment: UDP is a connectionless protocol that doesn't guarantee delivery. It is probably not a very good choice for a chatroom.

Comment: @molbdnilo, yeah, but: let's say we have 1000 users in a single channel. TCP requires to **always** keep the connection. Server will require some resources to hold all the connections. What about 10k users? Server will need many resources to keep all these 10k connections, and UDP seems to be a good choice as it's connection-less and does not require to always keep these connections

Comment: you need to keep sending pulse and send some data with the pulse when you need to send data. also on the receiving end detect connection lost if the pulse is not received for some time period you set. a pulse can be an empty json string.

Comment: What kind of server do you have? An Arduino?

Comment: A raspberry one, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to send a pulse or a heartbeat to keep the socket open. The socket will remain open as long as the program is running or you call *close* on it.

You can wrap your send and receive in an infinite loop but you should note that the example code you linked to is waaaay too simple for a chat client: you will need to handle errors like the *underlying* connection being offline ( for example, the interface being disconnected/ brought down, when the send and recv calls will return an error with associated errno ). You should look into using the *select*, *poll* and *epoll* system calls to detect errors and deal with them.